# Symfony : How can I optimize Doctrine query?

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, query-optimization

I want to know how I can optimize my Doctrine queries because some of my queries are too long.

I don't want a method particularly to my query, but common methods I can apply to all requests, because I don't find information about this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are some tips to make Doctrine perform better:

http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/improving-performance/en#improving-performance

The changes that I've noticed make the biggest change:

- Use array hydration instead of object hydration whenever possible (it's MUCH more efficient)
- Don't use magic finders except when writing prototype code
- Doctrine has very nice caching utilities; Setup a query and a result cache for your queries if you haven't yet (it's very automated and easy to setup: http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/caching/en)
- Remember to join all the relations that you use in your processing code in the DQL query; not doing so will make Doctrine launch a "hidden" query for every access to an unfetched relation.